# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ((n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{1/3} - n)$

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

I am trying to find the limit of the following sequence as $n \to \infty$.

> $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ((n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{1/3} - n)$$

At first glance, this limit looks like $\infty - \infty$, which is indeterminate. I do not have access to L'Hospital's rule yet, so I tried to multiply by the quantity
$$
1 = \frac{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} + n}{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} + n},
$$
which treats the cubed root in the numerator but creates a problem in the denominator. After simplifying, the limit turns into
$$
\frac{n^3 + n + 1}{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} + n}.
$$
I then tried dividing the numerator and denominator by $n^3$. The numerator simplifies nicely, but the factor $(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3}$ does not. I can work the $n^3$ into the cubed root either by writing $n^3 = (\sqrt{n})^3$ or by rewriting the root as
$$
(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} = \frac{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^2}{n^3}.
$$
I then tried to expand out the numerator of this and cancel, but I still have several terms with powers of $n$. I don't think I can divide by a higher power of $n$ at risk of creating an expression in the overall numerator $n^3 + n + 1$ that goes to $0$. So I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Are you familiar with evaluating limits of the form $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^{a} - 1}{x}$ for $a > 0$? If so, can you transform the given limit into the form above?

Comment: @sudeep5221 I'm afraid I don't. If $a$ were an integer, I would try to use the binomial theorem, but it seems that it can be an arbitrary positive real number.

Comment: I don't know how you got that simplification, but what you'd really want to do is let $N = (n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{1/3}$, and multiply by$$\frac{N^2 + Nn + n^2}{N^2 + Nn + n^2}.$$This makes the numerator $N^3 - n^3 = n^2 + n + 1$.

Answer (score 4):

for $n > 0,$

$$  \left(n + \frac{1}{3} \right)^3 < n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 <  \left(n + \frac{1}{3}  + \frac{1}{n} \right)^3  $$

so that

$$ n + \frac{1}{3}  < \left(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1  \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}<  n + \frac{1}{3}  + \frac{1}{n}   $$

Let's see; you can verify the inequalities in the first line by simply multiplying out the displayed cubes. As to finding them, I knew $ n + \frac{1}{3} $  would work out, then I experimented with $n + \frac{1}{3}  + \frac{A}{n}  $  and varied $A$

The following, more precise, bounds do need $n \geq 1,$  in case $n$ is not an integer

$$  \left(n + \frac{1}{3} +  \frac{2}{9n} +  \frac{14}{81n^2} -  \frac{46}{243n^3} \right)^3 < n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 < 
  \left(n + \frac{1}{3} +  \frac{2}{9n} +  \frac{14}{81n^2}
 \right)^3 
 $$

Comment: very clever (+1)

Comment: Your initial $n>1$ is not even needed, or is it? (+1) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead multiply the limit in such way, that you get difference of cubes in the numerator. By multiplying with $\displaystyle \frac{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} + n(n^3+n^2+n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^2}{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} + n(n^3+n^2+n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^2}$.

You should get $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n^2+n+1}{(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)^{2/3} + n(n^3+n^2+n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^2}}$

We can write numerator as $\displaystyle n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ and denominator as $\displaystyle n^2\left(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n^3}+\frac{3}{n^4}+\frac{2}{n^5}+\frac{1}{n^6}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^2\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^2$.

If we let $n\to \infty$ inside all of these braces.
We get $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{3n^2}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(n^3+n^2+n+1)^{\frac 1 3}=n\left(1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}+\frac 1{n^3}\right)^{\frac 1 3}= n \, A$$

$$\log(A)=\frac 13 \log\left(1+\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}+\frac 1{n^3}\right)$$

Use the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ with $x=\frac 1n+\frac 1{n^2}+\frac 1{n^3}$ and then binomial expansion

$$\log(A)=\frac{1}{3 n}+\frac{1}{6 n^2}+\frac{1}{9 n^3}-\frac{1}{4
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Taylor again with
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=1+\frac{1}{3 n}+\frac{2}{9 n^2}+\frac{14}{81 n^3}-\frac{46}{243 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$n \,A-n=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{9 n}+\frac{14}{81 n^2}-\frac{46}{243
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which is a very good approximation even for small values of $n$.

For example, for $n=10$ the exact value is
$$\sqrt[3]{1111}-10=   0.35709643$$ while the approximarion gives
$$\frac{43387}{121500}=0.35709465$$ corresponding to an absolute error of $1.78\times 10^{-6}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;a(n)=\dfrac1n+\dfrac1{n^2}+\dfrac1{n^3}\;$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,.$

You could proceed as follows :

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+n+1}-n\right)=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac1n+\dfrac1{n^2}+\dfrac1{n^3}}-1\right)=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sqrt[3]{1+a(n)}-1\right)=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n\left(\sqrt[3]{1+a(n)}-1\right)\left(\!\sqrt[3]{\big[1\!+\!a(n)\big]^2}\!+\!\sqrt[3]{1\!+\!a(n)}\!+\!1\!\right)}{\sqrt[3]{\big[1+a(n)\big]^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+a(n)}+1}=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n\left(\sqrt[3]{\big[1+a(n)\big]^3}-1\right)}{\sqrt[3]{\big[1+a(n)\big]^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+a(n)}+1}=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n\,a(n)}{\sqrt[3]{\big[1+a(n)\big]^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+a(n)}+1}=$

$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1+\dfrac1n+\dfrac1{n^2}}{\sqrt[3]{\big[1+a(n)\big]^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+a(n)}+1}=\dfrac13$

since $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a(n)=0\;.$

Answer (score 0):

Each sequence element verifies
$$\frac13\;<\;\left[n^3+n^2+n+1\right]^\frac13-n\;\:<\;\frac13+\frac1{3n}$$
from which convergence of the sequence towards $\frac13\,$ is immediate.
The upper bound on the RHS is won from the Geometric-Arithmetic mean inequality
$$\Big[\,(1+n)\left(\tfrac1n+n\right)n\,\Big]^\frac13-n \;<\;
\frac{1+n\;+\;\frac1n+n\;+\;n}{3\quad} -n \;=\; \frac13\;+\;\frac1{3n}\,.$$
The stricter "$<$" holds instead of "$\leqslant$" as $\,n,\, n+\tfrac1n,\, n+1\,$ never coincide.
The lower bound invokes
$$\left(\,n+\tfrac13\right)^3\;=\; n^3+n^2+\tfrac13n+\tfrac1{27}\;<\;n^3+n^2+n+1$$
which is Will Jagy's smart observation in his answer.
Alternatively, the Harmonic-Geometric mean inequality yields the lower bound
$$\frac{n^2+n+2}{3n^2+2n+2+\frac1n} \;=\;
\frac3{\frac1{1+n}+\frac1{\frac1n + n}+\frac1n}-n \;<\; 
\Big[\,(1+n)\left(\tfrac1n+n\right)n\,\Big]^\frac13-n$$
which is slightly sharper on the one hand, on the other hand it is computationally more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it using a generalized version of the binomial theorem.

$1+n+n^2+n^3 = \frac{n^4-1}{n-1}=(n+1)(n^2+1)=(n+1)^3-2n(n+1)$

$[(n+1)^3-2n(n+1)]^{1/3} = (n+1)[1-\frac{2n}{(n+1)^2}]^{1/3}$

$(1+x)^{1/3}\approx (a+bx+cx^2)$

$(1+x)=(a+bx+cx^2)[a^2+2abx+(b^2+2ac)x^2+2bcx^3+c^2x^4 ]$

$1+x\approx  a^3+3a^2bx+(3ab^2+3a^2c)x^2 +(6abc+b^3)x^3$

$a=1$

$b=1/3$

$3/9+3c=0\implies c=-1/9$

$(1+x)^{1/3} \approx 1+x/3-x^2/9<1+x/3$

$ 1+x/3-x^2/9<(1+x)^{1/3}<1+x/3$

$x=\frac{-2n}{(n+1)^2}$

$(n+1)[1-\frac{2n}{3(n+1)^2}-\frac{4n^2}{9(n+1)^4}]-n<(1+n+n^2+n^3)^{1/3}-n< (n+1)[1-\frac{2n}{3(n+1)^2}]-n$

Now squeeze between upper and lower values.

$1-\frac{2n}{3(n+1)}- \frac{4n^2}{9(n+1)^3}\le (1+n+n^2+n^3)^{1/3}-n \le 1-\frac{2n}{3(n+1)}$

$1/3-\epsilon\le (1+n+n^2+n^3)^{1/3}-n \le 1/3$